# Python Stacked barchart with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a data frame I have with a stacked barchart, where the x is websites, the y is frequency and then the groups on the barchart are different groups using them.
This is the dataframe:
[image]

This is the plot created just by doing this:

`web_data_roles.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10))`

[image]

As you can see its not what I want, vie tried changing the plot so the axes match up to the different columns of the dataframe but it just says no numerical data to plot, Not sure how to go about this anymore. so all help is appreciated

Comment: You didn't specify `x` or `y`, so the API will only plot numeric data or dates. Use seaborn. `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.barplot(data=web_data_roles, x='freq', y='website', hue='role', dodge=False)`.

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(15).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organise your dataframe so that **role** is a column.

1. `set_index()` initial preparation
2. `unstack()` to move **role** out of index and make a column
3. `droplevel()` to clean up multi index columns

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=[10,5],
                      sharey=False, sharex=False, gridspec_kw={"hspace":0.3})

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""website,role,freq
www.bbc.co.uk,director,2000
www.bbc.co.uk,technical,500
www.twitter.com,director,4000
www.twitter.com,technical,1500
"""))

df.set_index(["website","role"]).unstack(1).droplevel(0,axis=1).plot(ax=ax, kind="barh", stacked=True)
```

[image]